# How to finish activity in javainterface class webview android?

Tags: android, webview, android-dialog

I have webview . I want HTML data so i used

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebInterface(this), "HtmlViewer");
```

and Interface class

```
class WebInterface {

        private Context ctx;

        WebInterface(Context ctx) {
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showHTML(String html) {
            DialogManager.showCustomDialog("title", 
                    "msg", ctx, new DialogStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(int state) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I am calling finish but activity not destroyed.

I Also tried

```
onBackPressed();
```

and

```
((Activity) ctx).finish();
MyActivity.this.finish();
```

I just want to finish activity inside dialog.

Comment: Try to declare WebInterface as Interface instead of class.

Comment: have you pass activityname.this instead of this on your constructor?

Comment: yes. i also tried using activity.this in constructor.

Comment: Can you confirm that onclick() is called?

Comment: @Nguyen Doan Tung dialog state listner mot working . Perhapse for default alert dialog it working.